# WooCommerce: swap the content and the excerpt if the content is empty

Tags: php, sql, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

For some unknown reason in WooCommerce, on some products I have an excerpt but no content.

How could I with a script (MySQL or PHP) fix this, swapping the content and the excerpt ONLY if the content is empty?

The option to fix this on display only is not possible, as I have to do regular updates to my catalog and therefore really prefer to clean this catalog at the database level.

I saw on another post this option to swap columns, but I don't know how to adapt it to my situation:

```sql
    UPDATE wp_post AS p 
    SET p.post_content=(@temp:=p.post_content), 
    p.post_content = p.post_excerpt, 
    p.post_excerpt = @temp 
    WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
    AND  p.post_status = 'publish';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there is an error on the table name, it's `wp_posts`, but not `wp_post`.
To swap the "post excerpt" in the "post content" only when the post content is empty, you just need to add at the end of your query:

```sql
AND p.post_content = ''
```

So the complete query *(with the correct table name)* is:

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts AS p  
SET p.post_content=(@temp:=p.post_content), 
p.post_content = p.post_excerpt,  
p.post_excerpt = @temp 
WHERE p.post_type = 'product' 
AND  p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND p.post_content = '';
```

Tested and works